# Graphing the inequality $2x-4y > -6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

I originally had the following inequality

$$2x - 4y > -6 $$

I now have:

$$ 4y < 2x + 6 $$

It's almost in $y$ intercept form, only problem I have now is getting that $y$ by itself.

I think I have to divide everything by $4$, but I'm not sure, and I don't have answer key for this problem.

My final result is:

$$y < \frac{1}{2} x + 1.5 .$$

Can someone confirm this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right!

But you could get there much easily,$$4y \lt 2x + 6 $$

Now we divide the both sides of the inequality by $4$,

$$y \lt \frac x2 + \frac32$$

which is consistent to your result $y \lt \frac 12x + 1.5$

[Check here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4y%20%3C%202x%20%2b%206) for more.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely correct; we just add $4y$ to both sides of $2x - 4y > -6$ to get $2x > -6 + 4y$, then we just add 6 and end up with $2x + 6 > 4y$ or $y < 2x + 6$ then divide by four for the final answer. Good luck with the rest of your maths career!